# Como integrar o Sublime Text com algum repositório do Github

Tags: github, sublime-text, commit

Possuo um repositório no GitHub, como integro esse repositório ao Sublime Text para fazer commit dos meus códigos fontes?

Procurei tutoriais, mas não encontrei.

Comment: Se você tiver a procura de plugins, pode usar https://packagecontrol.io/search/git . Após instalar o plugin, basta instalar o [**git**](https://git-scm.com/) > configurar e depois rodar (em seu terminal) `git clone <link do seu repositório>`

Comment: Usa o VsCode. É bem melhor que o sublime e já faz a integração automática com o GIT(basta ter instalado em seu pc e adicionado o endereço remoto do GitHub). Se seguir minha dica não vai se arrepender :)